# Reading geojson file to convert to sf

Tags: r, geojson, r-sf

I have a geojson file which i need to read/convert to sf object

I  read it with `geojsonR` package and it shows as lists of lists, but i need it to sf.
I tried using `st_read` as suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372599/in-r-how-to-read-in-geojson-file-modify-then-export-back-as-new-geojson-file) but it gives me `"Error:` dsn `must point to a source, not an empty string."`

Also tried `geojsonsf` package and `geojson_sf()` and it gives me `"Error in rcpp_geojson_to_sf(geojson, expand_geometries) : Invalid JSON"`

how can i read it as sf and more importantly - i need sf geometry from there...

The file is here https://vustaff-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/e5028514_vu_edu_au/ERKzUBrFobBKrNe7ga-3arMB63ZuyD4eDbAtPQ5fzy2BbQ?e=m87Af9

Comment: `geojson_sf` should work. Are you sure nothing is wrong with your file?

Comment: yes - it was a download from here https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/metadata/statistiske-enheter-grunnkretser/51d279f8-e2be-4f5e-9f72-1a53f7535ec1 i can read it with FROM_GeoJson_Schema from library geojsonR - but it is list of lists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at your 'json' (it's not valid .geojson) you'll see it's actually a set of nested geojson objects

Using your example, I'm

1. reading the .geojson (which is actually .json) file as plain text using `readLines`.
2. Inspecting the first-level properties using `jqr`

```r
txt <- paste0(readLines("~/Downloads/test.geojson"), collapse = "")
library(jqr)
jq(txt, "keys")

# [
#   "grunnkretser.delomradegrense",
#   "grunnkretser.fylkesgrense",
#   "grunnkretser.grensesjo",
#   "grunnkretser.grunnkrets",
#   "grunnkretser.grunnkretsgrense",
#   "grunnkretser.kommunegrense",
#   "grunnkretser.riksgrense",
#   "grunnkretser.territorialgrense"
# ]
```

See there are 8 different geojson objects.

You can read each of them by filtering the json before parsing through `geojsonsf` or `sf`

```r
library(geojsonsf)
library(sf)

sf_delomradegrense <- jq(txt, '.["grunnkretser.delomradegrense"]') %>% 
  geojsonsf::geojson_sf()

sf_delomradegrense
# Simple feature collection with 10284 features and 7 fields
# Geometry type: LINESTRING
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 4010764 ymin: 3853260 xmax: 5097468 ymax: 5425159
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# First 10 features:
#   objid datafangstdato folgerterrengdetalj malemetode oppdateringsdato         objtype noyaktighet                       geometry
# 1      1           <NA>                             99   20160126000000 Delområdegrense        <NA> LINESTRING (4404964 4628261...
# 2      2           <NA>                             99   20131027000000 Delområdegrense        <NA> LINESTRING (4616126 5145684...
# 3      3           <NA>                             99   20131027000000 Delområdegrense        <NA> LINESTRING (4101761 4257071...
# 4      4           <NA>                             99   20131027000000 Delområdegrense        <NA> LINESTRING (4129652 4122672...
# 5      5           <NA>                             99   20170908000000 Delområdegrense        <NA> LINESTRING (4303917 4481500...
# 6      6           <NA>                             99   20131027000000 Delområdegrense        <NA> LINESTRING (4607806 5150974...
# 7      7           <NA>                             99   20131027000000 Delområdegrense        <NA> LINESTRING (4300691 4485384...
# 8      8           <NA>                             99   20170712000000 Delområdegrense        <NA> LINESTRING (4396353 4104326...
# 9      9           <NA>                             99   20170908000000 Delområdegrense        <NA> LINESTRING (4396353 4104326...
# 10    10           <NA>                             99   20131027000000 Delområdegrense        <NA> LINESTRING (4627750 5166350...
```

---

Also note that .geojson [*must* be in CRS 4326](https://stevage.github.io/geojson-spec/#section-4) for it to be valid. It doesn't look like this data is.

Comment: i never used jqr - thank you for pointing it!
also - your solution is amazing! it worked! i was trying to get each item and then unnest the list - but this is much quicker and simpler!